# Como usar o git para organizar o meu ambiente de desenvolvimento, homologação e produção?

Tags: git, testes, versionamento

Estamos adotando o uso de um servidor de homologação aqui em nossa empresa, porém ainda não sabemos como organizar o fluxo de desenvolvimento a partir deste paradigma, já que atualmente cada desenvolvedor quando deseja consolidar as modificações implementadas realiza *push* ou *merge* diretamente para **origin/master**, utilizando ou não um *branch* para isto.

Esta relação ocorre apenas entre a máquina do desenvolvedor e o servidor de produção, que por sua vez possui em cada repositório o respectivo script **hooks/post-receive** para realização automatizada de deploy para o diretório **/var/www**.

O nosso novo ambiente funcionará conforme a figura abaixo, onde cada quadrado é um **remote** e cada círculo representa um **branch** fixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ainda não defini se no ambiente de homologação o projeto será executado a partir do *branch* **teste** e no *origin* (produção) utilizarei somente o *branch* **master**, ou se realizarei esta distinção apenas a partir do *remote*, sendo os projetos de ambos executados a partir do mesmo *branch* **master**, pois não sei a solução ideal nestes casos. O que vocês me sugerem? Como vocês costumam usar com suas equipes?

Answer (score 2):

Aqui no trabalho temos o master como a versão "sempre implantável" de acordo com o [github flow](https://guides.github.com/introduction/flow/index.html), para cada feature criamos um branch "correcao_xxx", apos testado, é aberto um pull request, analisado, aprovado e integrado ao master. Bem simples. (claro, utilizamos o GitHub para facilitar esse processo).

Outra possibilidade (que eu acho bem interessante), é criar um branch que comporte as alterações da iteração corrente (sprint, por exemplo, um nivel abaixo do master.), acredito que esse possa ser considerado o seu branch de "desenvolvimento", com novos branchs menores representando as features. Apos o sprint, integra-se no master (branch de produção) e fecha a versão (tag).

Mas tudo depende da sua necessidade, uma boa forma de pensar é se questionar "isso faz sentido? quando vou precisar desse remote? e desse branch?"

Comment: execelente sugestão. A empresa em que trabalho, por não ser do ramo de desenvolvimento de software, possui uma cultura mais conservadora, por isso, em nosso caso não é possível utilizar o GitHub para facilitar este processo, porém, de qualquer forma é muito interessante trabalhar com pull requests. Também creio que adotar um branch diferente para homologação e outro para produção seja a melhor alternativa, apesar de ainda ser necessário trabalhar com diferentes remotes, já que temos dois servidores diferentes para cada situação.